# NodeJS.Readablestream to DOM?

Tags: node.js, browser

I have a NodeJS.Readablestream which is a png image

How do I append it to dom? I'm trying to do this in the browser. I can't just add it to the `<img>` since it only has `src=""` which is supposed to be an url.

Comment: "Append to DOM" is something that only happens in the browser, not on your server.  So, please describe in detail WITH CODE what you are trying to do with the stream you have and whether this is on your server or code running in the webpage in the browser?

Comment: I suspect you would be best served by changing your architecture a bit and not generating the readablestream until the browser requests an URL for this image so please show a lot more server-side code so we can see exactly what you're trying to do here and where the image comes from and how the stream is created for it.

Comment: This was a bit bad question, but I switched to using https://www.npmjs.com/package/qrcode

and used the method toDataUrl() which you can just set to the url attribute of img html element in the browser. No more issues.

Before I was using a different NPM package which only returned ReadableStream.

Comment: Note, if you're putting large images or lots of images in data urls, this will seriously slow down the time it takes to render your page because the page HTML itself gets a lot larger as it contains all the image data.  For small images (like glyphs) this is fine.  For one modest size image, it's fine.  For lots of images, it will mess with the load time for your web page quite a bit.  There's a reason a regular web page is designed so the HTML can load, be parsed and display and the browser retrieves the images separately.  It also completely defeats image caching by the browser.

Comment: Usually a better design is to create a unique URL for each image, put that URL in the web page, let the browser parse the HTML, request the image URL and have your server send the image only when the browser requests it.